# Have Web viewer display local Host (http://127.0.0.1:8000/)

Tags: javascript, python, django, app-inventor

Currently I have a website built in python (Django) and have been using the browser (http://127.0.0.1:8000/) for testing the website. I am now entering the app development phase and would like to use the webviewer to display my site that is seen through the browser while running the python project.

My current setup is this:

Blocks:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any assistance would be much appreciated.